# Parsing using scan and regex

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I need to use `scan` in particular to get the data and the data only between two values using `scan` and a regex expression.

The values aren't static so I can't match using them.

Let me rephrase it, i need the value only. So something that allows me to get everything after `id="results" value="` and before `"`

```
id="results" value="/randompath/lol.jpg"
```

Comment: You might be looking for a xml parser or in this case you also might have some weird html so I would suggest to try [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Comment: I can only use scan for this, i made the goal a bit clearer with an edit.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken.  Nokogiri mentioned above is a fine choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no clue what you're actually searching for but if you want to extract the value of the attribute `value` in that string (assuming double quotes).

You can use this regex:

```
(?:^|\s|")value(?:\s+)?=(?:\s+)?(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])+)")
```

But for sure any html/xml parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) would be better if you can use one.

Comment: That sort of works but it needs to be based on `id="results" value=` so i only get one result back. with only value i get too many results

Comment: `(?:^|\s|")id="results"(?:\s+)?value(?:\s+)?=(?:\s+)?(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])+)")`

Comment: But that's even more ugly than before because it requires the order to be correct. The one before only required double quotes.

Comment: Okay you are more than correct, this is far too complex and I've pushed for use of a html parser instead, this is not feasible. Thank you so much your help!